# Rails link_to problem when using multiple host-based routing constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on integrating two existing Rails 6 applications. I currently have two sites, `www.example.com` and `community.example.com`, and I want to merge them into a single application while preserving the existing subdomain separation.

To this end, I'm using [Rails request-based constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints), which generally works as documented. I've combined my routes files with these constraints and the two subdomains function independently, each with their own unique routes, etc. Any `link_to` helpers I use point to the correct domain based on the defined routes. My constraint looks like this:

```
constraints :host => 'www.example.com' do
```

I'm running into a problem, however, when I try to adapt this to allow for different hostnames used for development, staging, and production. The constraint above will work fine in production but not anywhere else.

It's not documented on the page I linked above, but routing constraints will also accept an array or regex in place of a simple string, which would theoretically solve my problem, like so:

```
constraints :host => [ 'www.example.com', 'staging.example.com' ] do
```

This works fine for routing, but it causes `link_to` helpers to always link to the current domain rather than the appropriate one based on the routes.

To illustrate, here's a link used throughout the site to a page that exists on the "www" domain only:

```
<%= link_to('Catalog', products_url) %>
```

If I pass a single string in my routing constraints, this link will work correctly on both subdomains (ie, on pages on the "community" domain, the link points to the "www" domain).

If I use an array or regex in my routing constraint, the link above will always point to the current domain the link appears on, rather than being scoped by the defined routes. If this link appears on one of the "community" pages, it will not point to the correct "www" host.

Note that the routes themselves work fine when I uses an array constraint. It's only the link helper that breaks.

Passing a "host" argument like this does solve this, but it's prone to error, not really scalable, and also doesn't address the dev/staging problem.

```
<%= link_to('Catalog', products_url, :host => 'www.example.com') %>
```

The other option I see to make this work across my development/staging/production domains is to point the constraints to a class that will use a `matches?` method to handle the multi-domain logic, as described under the [Advanced Constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) heading in the docs. This also works for routing but causes the same problem in my link helpers.

Is this `link_to` behavior known or expected? Am I missing some simpler, obvious way to handle the dev/staging/production environments when creating these constraints? Or is this a fundamental shortcoming of doing anything but the most basic string matching in my constraints?

I've googled for solutions others have come up with for this but have come up short. Pointers welcome.

Comment: Little tip: you can use `subdomain: 'community'` instead of the  full host name. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Comment: @max This example is a bit simplified for brevity. My development environment uses a different domain name entirely, so I can't match just on subdomain. But, for what it's worth, I did test using  ```subdomain``` rather than ```host``` and found the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an environment variable to set the subdomain constraints? So, something like this:

```
constraints :host => ENV['www_domain'] do
constraints :host => ENV['community_domain'] do
```

Then you can use a gem like `dotenv` (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to set the correct subdomains in development, staging, production, etc.

Alternately, you could try setting the subdomains in the respective environment files. So in `config/environments/development` you could have something like:

```
config.x.domains.www = 'www.myapp.test'
config.x.domains.community = 'community.myapp.test'
```

And then in `config/environments/production` you could have:

```
config.x.domains.www = 'www.myapp.com'
config.x.domains.community = 'community.myapp.com'
```

And your constraints would look like:

```
constraints :host => Rails.configuration.x.domains.www do
constraints :host => Rails.configuration.x.domains.community do
```

I'm not sure that those would work, but seems like it's worth a shot.

Comment: The environment-specific hostname configuration worked perfectly. Thanks!